# The two rooms near or two rooms near

Tags: definite-article

In this sentence,

"Two rooms near mine were empty",

is it acceptable to place "the" in front of "two rooms"? I think that placing the "the" will result in making "two rooms" appear more specific. In that case, are both uses acceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends entirely on context.

The definite article implies that your reader/hearer will find the entity it marks completely identifiable.

So if your reader/hearer already knows that there were exactly two rooms near yours she knows exactly which two rooms you are talking about and the definite article will be appropriate.

But if she doesn't know how many rooms were near you, or knows that there were more than two rooms near you, she will not be able to identify which two rooms you are talking about and the definite article will be inappropriate.

Comment: Thank you. But what if it were in a novel, where the readers are not yet introduced to the specifics of the interior of the house? I read something like this in a novel and wondered if the author put "the" in front of "two rooms", it would specify that there are only two rooms besides the room considered mine.

Comment: I meant imply that there are only two rooms, even though the readers are not yet aware of that fact.

Comment: @user59694 In the novel case, a reader/hearer would understand the narrator's referents to reflect the reality of which he speaks and would take ***the** two rooms near mine* to entail thatonly these two rooms were near mine.